# Android HLS video mime type

Tags: android, android-intent, video-streaming, mime-types, http-live-streaming

I would like to fire an Intent to play a HLS (HTTP Live Stream) video.

What should I put in the type field to fire just the video players that support HLS?

I tried **unsuccessfully** the following:

```
video/m3u

video/m3u8

video/hls

application/x-mpegURL

vnd.apple.mpegURL

video/MP2T

application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
```

Ideas please...

Comment: The question relates to Android 3.0+, where HLS should be supported.

Comment: I'm successful playing HLS using mimetype 'video/*', but other players that do not support HLS can be fired as well, which results in crashes and freezes.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation regarding the HLS (HTTP Live Stream) mime type except:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html

Comment: Eventually, I used 'video/mp4' - from my tests, it gives a good enough result, because, from my experience, a lot of players handling 'video/mp4' can handle HLS as well.

Comment: ExoPlayer player please notice 「If your URI doesn’t end with `.m3u8`, you can pass `MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8` to `setMimeType` of `MediaItem.Builder` to explicitly indicate the type of the content.」[ref](https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html#using-mediaitem)

Answer (score 11):

You **should** put the Content-Type type specified in the RFC: **application/vnd.apple.mpegurl**. See section 3.1 of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-08

Android support for HLS is extremely poor. You will need some third party software on many devices, especially for versions less than 3. Google doesn't seem to care, or at least not to regression test.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, I already tried 'application/vnd.apple.mpegurl' without success. Thanks anyway for trying.

Answer (score 6):

Android code (ICS, JB) looks at the URL to determine player selection! If the URL contains the keyword m3u8, then and only then, will it play HLS.
This is obviously a bug in Android.

Comment: This seems to be true for Chrome 40 on Android 4.4.4. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28984555/202522

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue but "audio/x-mpegURL" seems to work as is what the sample HLS stream on Apples site uses http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8 - testing on a Galaxy Nexus BTW.

Bit confusing though hence why I'm looking around.

Comment: audio? I'd like to play video. The point is that there are a lot of video players out there - implemented by manufacturers and store apps. If they don't handle HLS but handle 'audio/x-mpegURL' - this will **NOT** work.

Comment: Don't disagree that "audio" makes no sense. I'm just mentioning that it's what triggers the native player on my Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: What native player? Google music?

Comment: Not Google Music. It's probably one of the few components in Android that isn't an app. If it is it's part of the Gallery app. BTW I've not tested this on Android 4.1 or 4.2, therefore no idea if this behaviour has changed (as it seems like a bug).

Comment: Everything is an app, whether built-in or installed. You can look at the log cat to see what it is. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I knew you would say that :) was too lazy to do that yest.

Answer (score 2):

The Mimetype for HLS format video is "application/x-mpegURL"

```
<video>
     <source src="example.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

This is according to Apple's official documentation (The creators of HLS).
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

When I used

```
<video id="player"
       src="http://hlsserver.example/auth/and/get/hls?authkey=42" 
       controls>
</video>
```

it failed with `videoElement.error == error.MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED` [1] on Chrome 40, even though Chrome requested the `src` URL three times as seen in tcpdump. This is the response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
[...]

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="Swedish",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="blah",LANGUAGE="swe"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=500000,SUBTITLES="subs"
/stream-proxy/blah1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=700000,SUBTITLES="subs"
/stream-proxy/blah2
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000,SUBTITLES="subs"
/stream-proxy/blah3
```

#### Footnotes

1. `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED` has a value of `4`.

### The solution

It seems like [thoma.ing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11800566/202522) is correct for Chrome 40 on Android 4.4.4 at least:

> Android code (ICS, JB) looks at the URL to determine player selection! If the URL contains the keyword m3u8, then and only then, will it play HLS. This is obviously a bug in Android.

When I changed the video `src` URL to include the `m3u8` keyword it started working perfectly fine on Chrome.

```
<video id="player"
       src="http://hlsserver.example/auth/and/get/hls?authkey=42&m3u8=yes"
       controls>
</video>
```

Comment: Hi. The question is about what mime-type to put in Android's intent, in order to be redirected to the appropriate activity/app. No html in the question - just a direct link to an HLS file.

Comment: My url is 
  
 https://blablamdev.testcompany.com/msng/cdcc/AppleHLS1/7eeccdce2.m3u8?media-auth=exp=162cd0cd91~acl=/mng/video meida id/*~hmac=61a45cdb6e6f9fde4835522ad40fe9df0a7a2f    , how should I change in java/android. i m getting error say " Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403" when play this video in exo player.