# ExoPlayer in Android not load with M3U8 + QueryParameter(auth)

Tags: android, video-streaming, mime-types, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I am using **com.google.android.exoplayer2** ( exoPlayer Version = 'r2.5.2')and I had to load / streaming videos like

```
> https://something.com/test/something.m3u8
```

It was working nicely.

But the requirement change and according to that changed the video ' URL's format' by adding some authenticate related parts to query parameter of the URL.

```
> https://something.com/test/something.m3u8?media-auth=exp=1623782763942~acl=/test/7dede44-djnjcndncj/*~hmac=3232434242
```

now the player is not loading this videos.

Error log shows this error.

> 2021-05-06 08:42:12.395 7020-7220/? E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:141)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:125)
> at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
> 2021-05-06 08:42:12.396 7020-7020/? E/VideoPlayerView: onError

```
HlsSource sourceHLS = new HlsSource(videoQuiz.video.id(),
                    videoQuiz.video.title(),
                    VideoHelper.prepareHlsVideoUriWithQuery("video URL"),
                    HlsSource.TIME_UNSET,
                    0,
                    HlsSource.TIME_UNSET,
                    0L, null);
            videoPlayerView.start(sourceHLS,
                    toUri(thumbnailUrl),
                    autoPlay,
                    getCurrentSegmentStartPosition());
            showQuestionAt(currentQuestionPosition);
```

And below I mentioned how I changed "prepareHlsVideoUriWithQuery" method.

```
public static Uri prepareHlsVideoUriWithQuery(String thisUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("video URL");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme(url.getProtocol())
            .encodedAuthority(url.getAuthority())
            .encodedPath(url.getPath().substring(1))
            .encodedQuery("video-auth=exp=24244~test=/test/232323-3232323/*~test=24242c0232n3223");

    return builder.build();
}
```

So,which place I have to change to load m3u8+authstring in exo player?

and any thought about set mimetype describe here [Android HLS video mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178321/android-hls-video-mime-type/28984555#28984555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find a solution,

When Initialize the class, I added

```
private static final CookieManager DEFAULT_COOKIE_MANAGER;
static
{
    DEFAULT_COOKIE_MANAGER = new CookieManager();
    DEFAULT_COOKIE_MANAGER.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
}
```

In OnViewCreated(),

```
    if (CookieHandler.getDefault() != DEFAULT_COOKIE_MANAGER)
    {
        CookieHandler.setDefault(DEFAULT_COOKIE_MANAGER);
    }
```

And when Data source create to load, Instead of

> final DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(..)

I added

```
    DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(MediaHelper.USER_AGENT);
    dataSourceFactory.getDefaultRequestProperties().set("Cookie", "cookieValue");
```

Then it Works!

Comment: Could you please share full source from init to play hls , sir?

Comment: @DươngNguyễnVăn actually this answer is the full code, "When Initialize the class", "OnViewCreated()", "when Data source create to load" these are the 3 steps, I added what to do within the steps. So carefully read the answer.

Comment: can you share the full code with a working video URL ?please

Comment: @AnsalRabin I think it should work if you clearly follow the steps mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the ExoPlayer docs, [`InvalidResponseCodeException`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/HttpDataSource.InvalidResponseCodeException.html) is thrown when an attempt to open a connection results in a response code not in the 2xx range.

The error message is telling you that the server has rejected the request with response code [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), meaning you are forbidden from accessing the resource.

Given it used to work before authentication was enabled, it seems most likely that your token generation code isn't working properly and is generating a token that the server deems invalid.

Comment: as per the document you mention,(exo player doc) you are correct, but the thing is I tested the same development in IOS app, this URL is working and query parameter seems okay. Then there should be a another reason in android exo player I have, for m3u8 + "auth query" url.

Comment: In your builder, you have two keys (`exp`, `test`) and you appear to be setting the `test` key twice (`test=/test/232323-3232323/*`, `test=24242c0232n3223`), whereas the example you give at the top has three keys (`exp`, `acl`, `test`). Is the builder definitely doing the right thing here? Surely you need to set the `acl` key in the builder? Also, the endpoints differ (`test-auth` vs `video-auth`), but I assume that is on purpose.

Comment: " exp=14637437e~acl=/msnt/4837483-bb1e3ee-323-832e23-2323cnds/*~hmad=65b64d32323370e " this is the correct format.

Comment: I edited the queryparameter which is in my question..with the correct elements.